# the android app crashes after 6 seconds when I press record button

Tags: java, android

```
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recording...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Do something after 6s
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Stopped Recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        mediaRecorder.stop();
                        mediaRecorder.release();
                        setupMediaRecorder();
                    }
                }, 6000);
```

**The app crashes after 6 seconds when I start recording, here is my setup media recorder function:**

```
   private void setupMediaRecorder()
{
    mediaRecorder= new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.OGG);
   // mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.OGG);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(pathSave);
}
```

**logcat:**
The error occurs at mediaRecorder.Stop(); in handler

```
2019-10-10 01:11:49.942 21574-21574/com.example.parkinsonsdisease E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.parkinsonsdisease, PID: 21574
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaRecorder._stop(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(MediaRecorder.java:1378)
    at com.example.parkinsonsdisease.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:93)
```

Comment: Possibly mediaRecorder is null.

Comment: Use Android Logcat to view the stack trace of exception!

Comment: @LeoLeontev I can't paste the screenshot of logcat here due to my reputation. 2019-10-10 01:11:49.942 21574-21574/com.example.parkinsonsdisease E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.parkinsonsdisease, PID: 21574
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaRecorder._stop(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(MediaRecorder.java:1378)
        at com.example.parkinsonsdisease.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:93)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following the steps given in MediaRecorder [State diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmK0x.gif), I used set encoder and output format in this order and solved the problem facing above:

```
    private void setupMediaRecorder()
{
    mediaRecorder= new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(pathSave);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation:

> public void stop ()
>
> ...
>
> Throws
>
> IllegalStateException if it is called before start()

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

As @LeoLeontev mentioned, it's most likely because you haven't called `prepare()` and `start()`.

Any call to `stop()` *must* be preceded by a call to `start()`, and `start()` must be preceded by a call to `prepare()`.

In other words,

```
private void setupMediaRecorder()
{
    mediaRecorder= new MediaRecorder();
    ...
    mediaRecorder.prepare();
}

private void startRecording()
{
    mediaRecorder.start();
}
```

See this diagram for reference:
[MediaRecorder State Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmK0x.gif)

Also, please see the `MediaRecorder` documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder).

Comment: unhandeled expection:JAVA.io.IOException error pops up when I call .prepare() function in setupmediarecorder()

Comment: @HamzaSaeed Are you on an emulator by chance?

Comment: You might also want to include the `AudioEncoder`. 

From the docs: [setAudioEncoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html?hl=en#setAudioEncoder(int))
"Sets the audio encoder to be used for recording. If this method is not called, the output file will not contain an audio track. Call this after setOutputFormat() but before prepare()."

Comment: No I am not using emulator.